# How to have multiple test environments with different configurations?

Tags: testing, symfony, phpunit

I have a Symfony 2 application, which uses a REST interace. I want to execute integrations tests with different environments. The tests should be executed:

- either against a real interface (running on a specific host)
- or against a mockup interface (running on localhost).

How can I specify, which test environment is executed? Currently I start tests using

```
phpunit -c app/
```

from within the application folder. However I dont want to duplicate the app folder.

**Update**

Specifically I have a REST service, which is responsible for doint REST calls, let's call it `RestBase`. At some point it builds up a URL like: `$urlPrefix.$restPath`. `$urlPrefix` is different for `dev`, `stage`, `prod` environments. Currently this configuration is done in `config_*.yml`. However I want to run tests against different `urlPrefix`. Conceptually I want to have something like:

```
phpunit -c app/ **-env=test**
```

where `urlPrefix` is `http://localhost:8888` and

```
phpunit -c app/ **-env=test2**
```

runs against another another environment, with a different setting for `urlPrefix`.

**Summarized question**

How to execute tests in another environment than `test`, e.g. `test2` (and not change this programmatically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom `bootstrap.php` as it is described here: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/10/symfony2-use-a-bootstrap-file-for-your-phpunit-tests-and-run-some-console-commands/

I then start the configuration using:

```
phpunit -c app/mockup.phpunit.php
```

To run tests against the real interface using:

```
phpunit -c app/
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are functional testing you REST api using phpunit.

Symfony2 already provides a way to bypass front controllers by directy calling your http Kernel.

All you have to do is to extend the WebTestCase class (inheriting itself from Phpunit Test_Case):

```php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class MyControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
public function testGET()
{
    // Create a new client to browse the application
    $client = static::createClient();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/api/v1/test');
    $this->assertTrue(200 === $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
}
}
```

Comment: Thats clear. How to have a url prefix basing on a test environment? E.g.: `$this->container->getParameter("urlPrefix")."/api/va1/test"`.

Comment: Note that it is clear to me, how to have different values for `urlPrefix` in general. My question is how to use different test environment, i.e. how to execute tests in another environment than `test`, e.g. `test2`.

Comment: Just add an array of options: `$client = static::createClient(array('environment' => 'test2'));`

Comment: Good to know, but I want to pass the environment to the test, and do not want to change this programmatically.

Comment: Then use ENV variables using `getenv` or CLI arguments using `$_SERVER['argv']['env']`;

Comment: I did not want to spread configuration in source code files. Thanks for the tipps.